# Plugin gerou XXX de caracteres inválidos durante ativação

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou estudando criação de plugins para WordPress e, como parte inicial dos meus estudos é criar um plugin de administração de boletins escolares de estudantes de uma escola fictícia.

Eu preciso criar algumas tabelas no banco assim que o usuário ativar o plugin. De acordo com a [documentação do WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins), uma das formas de realizar isso seria criar as consultas SQL dentro do arquivo `main.php` no diretório inicial do plugin e depois registrar as funções com `register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'function');`.

Porém, ao salvar o arquivo principal do meu plugin e ativá-lo no painel administrativo do WordPress, a seguinte mensagem de aviso é gerada:

> O plugin gerou 808 caracteres de saída inesperada durante a ativação.
>   Se você notar mensagens de "cabeçalhos já enviados", problemas com
>   feeds ou outros problemas, tente desativar ou remover este plugin.

Ao verificar o banco, noto que nem a tabela e muito menos os registros foram inseridos. Não consigo entender quais seriam esses caracteres adicionais uma vez que não teria como debugar meu código para identificar o erro.

Segue abaixo meu código. Agradeço desde já toda ajuda!

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Boletim de Notas
 * Plugin URL: http://www.edinaldoribeiro.com.br
 * Description: Plugin de administração de notas e geração de boletins escolares online.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Requires at least: 5.2
 * Requires PHP: 7.2
 * Author: Edinaldo Ribeiro
 * Author URI: http://www.edinaldoribeiro.com.br
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */

defined('ABSPATH') or die('Página indisponível');

global $db_version;
$db_version = '1.0';

function install_plugin(){

    global $wpdb;
    global $db_version;

    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "estudantes";
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        name tinytext NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unnamed',
        age INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        url varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);

    add_option('db_version', $db_version);
}

function install_plugin_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $name = "Edinaldo Ribeiro";
    $age = '23';

    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'estudantes';

    $wpdb->insert(
        $table,
        array(
            'time' => current_time('mysql'),
            'name' => $name,
            'age' => $age
        )
    );
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install_plugin');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install_plugin_data');
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolver o problema no dia seguinte, com a cabeça mais fresca, rsss..
Vou deixar a solução, talvez possa ajudar alguém no futuro.

O erro estava no SQL Statement dentro da função `install_plugin()` e os caracteres inválidos eram apenas os NOTICES e WARNING que o PHP estavam retornando ao tentar executar a consulta errada.

Segue como ficou o SQL. O restante do código não foi alterado.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        name tinytext NOT NULL,
        age INT NOT NULL,
        url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
```